# Crashlytics: dSYM Uploaded but Crash Reports Missing

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Under “Latest Release” it shows 100+ crashes and 94.9% crash-free users, but when I click in to investigate the crashes there are none there.  Originally I saw the upload dSYM warning.  I uploaded the dSYM and it looked to be successful.  I no longer see the dSYM warning, but I still am not seeing any crashes.

Why are the crash reports not displaying?

Answer (score 1):

It took ~3 hours after the dSYM file was uploaded to see the crash reports.

Answer (score 1):

Our dSYM uploads for unsymbolicated crashes are processed in the following 6 hours after your dSYMs are uploaded.